# Check column A in table 1 if contains value from column A in table 2 and return the value of column B table 2

Tags: r, dataframe, search, match, grepl

In the this example, I am trying to see whether values in column A in table 1 appear within the values in column A table 2.

If it does I want to add column B in table 1, which returns the value of column B in table 2 where the matches occur.

Desired output:

Table 1

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| dhjasd sd Y02sd | 105 |
| Y02 dsd | 105 |
| sds Y0545 dsas dds | 106 |
| Y093 sad |  |
| sd Y304sd |  |

Reference Table:

Table 2

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| Y01 | 102 |
| Y06 | 103 |
| Y02 | 105 |
| Y08 | 110 |
| Y0545 | 106 |

Can I please get any advice on how I should approach this? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `dplyr` you can do the following:

```
table1 |> 
  select(A) |> 
  mutate(values = stringr::str_extract(A, "Y\\d+")) |> 
  left_join(table2, by = c("values" = "A")) |> 
  select(A, B)

# A tibble: 5 × 2
  A                      B
  <chr>              <dbl>
1 dhjasd sd Y02sd      105
2 Y02 dsd              105
3 sds Y0545 dsas dds   106
4 Y093 sad              NA
5 sd Y304sd             NA
```

Comment: This works perfectly, thanks for your help Isaac! Just a quick question - if I want to match a column where the values are like CAT0LN, CAT2MJ, CAT99T,... what format should I use in the str_extract function to capture this?

Comment: You can replace `stringr::str_extract` with `str_extract(A, "CAT\\d+[A-Z]+")`